# How to update value in javascript Object without overwriting adjacent objects w/ same key

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble updating nested values in a Javascript Object with dynamically created keys. When attempting to select and update the non-unique nested key values (in a JQuery .each() loop) the update appears to set the value for ALL instances of that key.

Example Object:

```
var myThing = {
    uniqueItem1: {
        key_1: '',
        key_2: '',
        key_3: '',
    },
    uniqueItem2: {
        key_1: '',
        key_2: '',
        key_3: '',
    },
    uniqueItem3: {
        key_1: '',
        key_2: '',
        key_3: '',
    },
};
```

No matter what I try, updating a non-unique key in any nested object updates the other keys with the same value.

For example:

```
myThing.uniqueItem1.key_1 = 'original';
myThing.uniqueItem1.key_2 = 'recipe';
myThing.uniqueItem2.key_1 = 'chicken';

console.log(myThing.uniqueItem2.key_1) ==> 'chicken' returned, which is expected
console.log(myThing.uniqueItem1.key_1) ==> 'chicken' returned, when 'original' is expected
```

I seem to be missing something fundamental here - I prefer named indices à la an Object rather than an Array, but if I have to approach this from another angle I can.

UPDATE:  ಠ_ಠ So the example works like I would imagine it should. Which means the issue is somehow in how I am generating those second level objects.

What I am doing is reading a set of values from an XML file to create unique identifiers for the first level keys, then setting the value of those keys to a template object.

So in a nutshell:

```
 var uniqueItemTemplate = {
      key_1: '',
      key_2: '',
      key_3: '',
},
var uniqueStr = 'uniqueItem1';
myThing[uniqueItem1] = uniqueItemTemplate;
```

So the issue was indeed that I wasn't copying the object I was just referencing it (ugh I need to read up on prototypes but I am a nubbin'). I instead generated the necessary keys for each new object in the same loop that loads them, which resolved the issue.

Ex:

```
var uniqueStr = 'uniqueItem1';
myThing[uniqueStr] = {};
 myThing[uniqueStr]['hub_name'] = '';
 myThing[uniqueStr]['cell_name'] = '';
```

And it works. The more you know! ⭐

Comment: Are you sure that's what your ```myThing``` looks like? It's not valid Javascript

Comment: Show your actual initialization code, what you currently have is invalid syntax. But by your description it sounds like you made each property have the same object reference instead of a completely different object.

Comment: Need to see the loop to tell what it is doing

Comment: Once the typos are fixed, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/v5ax42te/

Comment: Updated to correct syntax because of the whole ': instead of = because I didn't proofread the example' thing. Oops.

Comment: Also look into `Object.assign`, as it's literally for extending values on an object with keys from another object.